# Two's complement overflow

Tags: python, binary

I am working on a program in python which adds numbers in two's complement. I would like to display the word "overflow" where overflow has occurred. This is homework, so I am not asking for the answer, nor will I post any code, I would just like help understanding the concept of overflow.

We have been given the following examples of the form overflow(decimal 1, decimal 2, number of bits):

- `overflow(1, -1, 2)` returns `01 + 11 = 00`
- `overflow(1, 1, 2)` returns `01 + 01 = 10 overflow`
- `overflow(127, 2, 8)` returns `01111111 + 00000010 = 10000001 overflow`
- `overflow(-1, -1, 2)` returns `11 + 11 = 10`
- `overflow(-128, 2, 8)` returns `10000000 + 00000010 = 10000010`

Now from my understanding, if the sum of two positive numbers yields a negative result, the sum has overflowed. Also, if the sum of two negative numbers yields a positive result, the sum has overflowed. If that's the case it should be easy to code. However doesn't that mean the second case should not give overflow? And that the fourth case should give overflow?

Comment: Do you think that `10` represents a positive number?

Comment: Try checking out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKTsv6iVxV4) - it's short (~15 minutes) and does a good job explaining Two's complement